# Haven't seen this in a while: jQuery is not defined on CiviMail 4.6.16

Tags: civimail, jquery

Yo dudes, let's get the con started with this classic!  Haven't seen this beast in a while.

1. recently updated to 4.6.16
2. theme Seven
3. ran update.php after upgrade
4. cleared Civi and Drupal cache
5. Drupal cache off

Still the issue with field selects and jQuery error is happening (attached images).  Feeling kind of duncey here. Any ideas?

Stuart

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing jQuery Update module fixed the issue.  The site was running a 'stock' Drupal 7.43 with no modules except Views, cTools and Webform.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you change themes to one of the basics?  This looks somewhat similar in end result to the Backbone errors that are occurring with some of the themes.  Do you see errors on the Manage Events -> Online Registration page also?

Comment: The "jQuery is undefined" is on all pages of CiviCRM.  It doesn't have the negative effect on Online Registration page that it does on New Mailing, however.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm--in theory Drupal jQuery Update shouldn't make a difference. Ye olde jQuery in Drupal is the reason CiviCRM has its own `CRM.$` or `cj` instead of regular `$` or `jQuery`.

Something must be using the wrong one.  If I had to guess, I'd say that some code isn't within a closure.

Comment: I'm a bit stumped as well.  Notice there is one less jQuery error in this screenshot: http://s33.postimg.org/x0rqi5y5r/now.png